# htaccess loading recursively when jquery load

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two URLs:

```
http://www.domain.com/catalogo
http://www.domain.com/catalogo/item1
```

My `.htaccess` header looks like this currently:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

    RewriteRule ^inicio$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^catalogo$ catalogo.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^catalogo/(.+) catalogo.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^empresa$ empresa.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^contacto$ contacto.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I load content into `catalogo.php` this way:

```
$("#contenido_catalogo").load("ajax_catalogo.php", {slu: 'lets_say_item1'}, function(){});
```

The first URL is loaded successfuly, but appending `/item1` to the URL makes `catalogo.php` load recursively instead of `ajax_catalogo.php`.

It seems that loading of `ajax_catalogo.php` matches the second *RewriteRule* and creates the endless loop, but I have no idea how to avoid it.

How should I do it instead? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe using the [R] flag would help?

Comment: It doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, adding `[L]` flag after each rule would be definitely good for you.
Then, either define a `RewriteBase` or use absolute paths in your rules.
Finally, disabling `MultiViews` option is also a good idea in your case.

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be **in root folder**)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^catalogo$ catalogo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^catalogo/(.+)$ catalogo.php/$1 [L]
```

Note: no need to worry about the order of your 2 rules in this case (they don't interfere)

---

EDIT:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^inicio$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^catalogo$ catalogo.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^catalogo/(.+)$ catalogo.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^empresa$ empresa.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^contacto$ contacto.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In fact my htaccess looks very much like yours. I've updated it in my question, just to be clear. I only added the L flag. It doesn't work anyway. ´$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']´ is ´/catalogo/item1´ the first loop, but ´/catalogo/ajax_catalogo.php´ for the rest of them. This may be a clue for you.

Comment: Ok you can see the solution in my edited answer (`EDIT` part). The check of `is not a file and is not a folder` was only applied for `inicio` (`RewriteCond` are for next `RewriteRule` only). That's why you had a loop with `catalogo/item1` because it was calling `catalogo.php/item1` again and again. I think you should also have `.load("/ajax_catalogo.php")` in your JS (with leading slash) if your file is in root folder